# How does process CPU usage relate to Load Average?

Tags: centos, unix, cpu-usage, load-average

I have the following host / load:

- Two 6-core CPUs, with HT (From what I understand, max load would be `24.0`)
- 12 "primary" processes, with sustained usage of about `50%` CPU
- `Load average: 0.86  0.98  0.98`

Could someone help me understand:

- How do multiple processes have sustained load, while the Load Average of the box is seemingly low? Considering 12 cores at 50%, I'd expect the load to at least hit somewhere between 6.0 - 12.0.
- Considering CPU usage alone, are there any low-level details preventing me from adding more services to this host until the Load average hits ~`24`? (not concerned about disk I/O, memory, or anything else for the sake of this question -- I just want to fully understand how reliable the `Load average` is when considering CPU bottle-necking; thread waiting? bus contention? anything that's not represented in the Load average concerning CPU use?)

Comment: This three part article on understanding Linux load average should help to explain how the load average is calculated: [https://prutser.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/understanding-linux-load-average-part-1/](https://prutser.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/understanding-linux-load-average-part-1/)

Answer (score 1):

Load is not the number of processes currently running on CPU, but the number waiting for CPU time. So if you have, say, 8 cores then 8 threads can use a full core each without the load being affected. (This is not a likely scenario as there are much more threads.)

Also, the only upper limit for the load is the number of processes that can run simultaneously on a system. I've seen values of 100 and more.